# Merging two bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

I have a few anonymous texts in the bibliography and I have to consult more than one edition/volumes of these texts. I want to sort the bib entries either according to the author or the name of the text. In the latter case, I get two entries in the bibliography, instead of one. How to avoid this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=philosophy-modern,
  publocformat=loccolonpub,
  inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

Here are the bibliographic entries:

```
@misc{
title = {Text},
  note =     {\textit{Text}, ed. by editor, Publisher, I, place},
  date =     date,
}

@misc{
title = {Text},
  note =     {\textit{Text}, ed. by editor, Publisher, II, place},
  date =     anotherdate,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `biblatex-philosophy`'s `philosophy-modern` style only collapses author/editor/translator lists. But with some work we can also make it honour the fallback titles that are used instead if there are no authors. This involves remembering the title we printed and checking if it coincides with the title we'd print again.

The macros `author`, `bbx:editor` and `bbx:translator` are taken from `philosophy-modern.bbx` and were only modified lightly (an added `\global\undef\bbx@lasttitle` if the names are defined and `\usebibmacro{labeltitle}` replaced by our new `\usebibmacro{printhead:labeltitle}`). `printhead:labeltitle` is based on `labeltitle` from `philosophy-classic.cbx`, but now does all the title equality checking and saves the printed title in `\bbx@lasttitle`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=philosophy-modern,
  publocformat=loccolonpub,
  inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{printhead:labeltitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {\iffieldequals{title}{\bbx@lasttitle}
          {\clearfield{title}}
          {\printfield{title}%
           \savefield{title}{\bbx@lasttitle}%
           \clearfield{title}%
           \postsep}}
       {\iffieldequals{shorttitle}{\bbx@lasttitle}
          {}
          {\printfield[title]{shorttitle}%
           \savefield{shorttitle}{\bbx@lasttitle}%
           \postsep}}%
     \blx@postpunct}
    {\iffieldequals{label}{\bbx@lasttitle}
       {}
       {\printfield{label}%
        \savefield{label}{\bbx@lasttitle}%
        \postsep}}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasttitle
     \usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {}%
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{}%
        {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield{nameaddon}}%*
        \postsep}%
     \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
       \iffieldundef{authortype}
         {}%
         {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
         \printtext{\addcomma\space}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{printhead:labeltitle}%
     \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
     }%
  }

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }%
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasttitle
   \usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
    {}%
    {\printnames{editor}%
          \postsep%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
    \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
    \usebibmacro{#1}%
    \clearname{editor}%
    \printtext{\addcomma\space}%
  }%
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
   \usebibmacro{printhead:labeltitle}%
   \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  }%
}%

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }%
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasttitle
   \usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
    {}%
    {\printnames{translator}%
          \postsep%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
    \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
    \usebibmacro{#1}%
    \clearname{translator}%
    \printtext{\addcomma\space}%
  }%
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
   \usebibmacro{printhead:labeltitle}%
   \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{a,
  title = {Text},
  note  = {\textit{Text}, ed. by editor, Publisher, I, place},
  date  = 2010,
}
@misc{b,
  title = {Text},
  note  = {\textit{Text}, ed. by editor, Publisher, II, place},
  date  = 2011,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with only one appearance of "Text" as header title.]

I should probably note that it is against the spirit of `biblatex` and `.bib` files to put all publication data into the `note` field. Usually it is preferable to use the `editor` field for editors, `publisher` for the publisher, `location` for the place etc. I also replaced `date = date` and `date = anotherdate` by real dates, because `date` and `anotherdate` were not valid in this setup and threw an error. I also had to add entry keys (`a` and `b`) to the entries as Biber would complain otherwise.

Comment: thanks, it worked! My publisher wants entries sorted either according to the author or the title. When I used separate fields as editor, publisher etc. then the entries are sorted according to author/editor.